# Why is this happening in BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

```
BigInteger bx=new BigInteger("3806908688");

byte x[]=new byte[4];

String s=bx.toString(10);

System.out.println("string: "+s);

x=s.getBytes();

int l=0,i=0;

l |= x[i] & 0xFF;

l <<= 8;

l |= x[i+1] & 0xFF;

l <<= 8;

l |= x[i+2] & 0xFF;

l <<= 8;

l |= x[i+3] & 0xFF;

System.out.println(l);
```

The output is `859320374` instead of `3806908688`. Why is this happening when I'm converting a BigInteger into a byte array and printing this byte array as an integer

I also tried using `bx.toByteArray()`  but the result is same

Comment: Clue: `int` can't hold 3806908688, it's too large. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

Comment: this all could happen because you use lower-case `l` as a variable.. no, seriously.. :)

Comment: It's ok that int cant hold it because it is too long. But when i tried to convert into byte array using bx.toByteArray() and again convert that byte array to BigInteger the value is changing.What is happening in this case

Comment: Show the new code. Better yet, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it manually, do it in a loop:

```
// Take care of negative values
long l = (bigInt.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) ? -1 : 0;
byte[] array = bigInt.toByteArray();
for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
    l |= array[i] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
}
l |= array[array.length-1] & 0xFF;
```

Alternatively you could just use methods offered by `BigInteger`:

```
int someInt = bigInt.intValue();
long someLong = bigInt.longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are working of the byte array of the string representation of the BigInteger. Use BigInteger.toByteArray() instead.

**Update:**
If I try this:

```
BigInteger bx = new BigInteger("3806908688");
byte[] bytes = bx.toByteArray(); 
BigInteger bxCopy = new BigInteger(bytes);

System.out.println("bx    : " + bx);
System.out.println("bxCopy: " + bxCopy);
```

Then the output is:

```
bx    : 3806908688
bxCopy: 3806908688
```

So this seems correct.

Comment: when i tried to convert into byte array using bx.toByteArray() and again convert that byte array to BigInteger the value is changing.What is happening in this case

Comment: Sorry, I meant BigInteger. Updated my response. I can convert BigInteger to byte array and back and the new BigInteger instance has the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use `BigInteger.toByteArray`, whatever you are doing with `.toString` and `.getBytes` won't work.

Secondly, `BigInteger.toByteArray` will return a byte array in twos-complement. As your number is greater than 2^31, it will take 5 bytes, not 4. See [Java BigInteger.toByteArray docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) . Or see the output of `System.out.println(x.length);`.

So you need:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

class BigIntegerTest {
    public static void main(final String[] argv) {
        BigInteger bx=new BigInteger("3806908688");

        byte x[]=new byte[5];

        x=bx.toByteArray();

        System.out.println(x.length);

        long l=0;
        int i=0;

        l |= x[i] & 0xFF;

        l <<= 8;

        l |= x[i+1] & 0xFF;

        l <<= 8;

        l |= x[i+2] & 0xFF;

        l <<= 8;

        l |= x[i+3] & 0xFF;

        l <<= 8;

        l |= x[i+4] & 0xFF;

        System.out.println(l);

    }
}
```

which yields:

```
5
3806908688
```

Note also that I'm using `long` not `int`, to ensure the value fits in the type.

You'd also be better off using a for loop:

```java
long l = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    l <<= 8;
    l |= x[i] & 0xFF;
}

System.out.println(l);
```

That way, you don't really need to know the length of the array explicitly. Although I'd still be careful to understand that it is in twos complement - who knows when you might accidently use minus numbers or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Because `bx.toString(10).getBytes()` is **10 bytes** (one for each digit of `3806908688`), not 4 bytes long as your code seems to assume (your "iteration" stops at 4).

Consider using a for loop, like this, which will work no matter how many bytes are in the number:

```
long l = 0; // long is large enough to hold your number 3806908688
for (byte b : x) {
    i |= b & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
}
```

Comment: when i tried to convert into byte array using bx.toByteArray() and again convert that byte array to BigInteger the value is changing.What is happening in this case

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` has a method `toByteArray`, use this to get at the bytes. First converting it to a string and get the bytes from there is rather ... strange.

Here's a test program that demonstrates how to convert to an byte array and back:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class TestBigInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger first = new BigInteger("12345678901234567890");
        System.out.println(first);
        BigInteger second = new BigInteger(first.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(second);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
```

Comment: when i tried to convert into byte array using bx.toByteArray() and again convert that byte array to BigInteger the value is changing.What is happening in this case